# Скрытие/отображение слоя в javaFX при выборе radio

Tags: java, javafx

Всем привет!

Впервые пишу на JavaFX, еще многие вещи не изучил, на данный момент возникла такая проблема:

Имеется fxml документ данного вида:

[image: заполнение данных в поля]

Необходимо, чтобы при выборе radio клавиши "NO", данные поля скрывались, при "YES" соответственно отображались.
В fxml документе они положены на AnchorPane. То есть пытался скрывать просто его. Но работало не точно.

```
<AnchorPane fx:id="additionalPane" layoutX="139.0" layoutY="346.0" prefHeight="137.0" prefWidth="639.0">
    <children>
        <TextField fx:id="needsSpecialtyField" layoutX="149.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="341.0" promptText="Necessary specialty" />
        <TextField fx:id="educationField" layoutX="149.0" layoutY="55.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="341.0" promptText="Education" />
        <TextField fx:id="expirienceField" layoutX="149.0" layoutY="96.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="341.0" promptText="Expirience" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Пробовал в классе-контроллере в методе инициализации указать параметр `setVisible(false/true)`, по типу:

```java
if (yesRadioButton.isSelected()) {
    yesRadioButton.setOnAction(event -> {
        additionalPane.setVisible(true);
    });
}
if (noRadioButton.isSelected()) {
    noRadioButton.setOnAction(event -> {
        additionalPane.setVisible(false);
    });
}
```

Но в данном случае, при старте программы по умолчанию стоит выбор "NO", но панель открыта, при переключение на "YES" и обратно на "NO" панель скрывается, но дальнейшие нажатия на "YES" не отображают панель.

Radio клавиши объеденины в ToggleGroup:

```java
ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();
yesRadioButton.setToggleGroup(group);
noRadioButton.setSelected(true);
noRadioButton.setToggleGroup(group);
```

Как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При инициализации независимо от состояния radiobutton нужно привязаться к событиям изменения их состояния. Поэтому оба `setOnAction` нужно вынести из условий, и отдельно установить начальное состояние видимости панели:

```
yesRadioButton.setOnAction(event -> {
    additionalPane.setVisible(true);
});

noRadioButton.setOnAction(event -> {
    additionalPane.setVisible(false);
});

additionalPane.setVisible(yesRadioButton.isSelected());
```

А вообще можно то же самое сделать одной строкой:

```
additionalPane.visibleProperty().bind(yesRadioButton.selectedProperty());
```

Т.е. свойство видимости панели связать со свойством состояния `yesRadioButton`, тогда при изменении состояния `yesRadioButton` будет автоматически меняться состояние видимости панели.